# CakePHP remove space in postal code inside where clause

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

Hi so I have this code to find some stuff for me.

```
$contractAddresses = $this->ContractAddresses->find()
    ->contain(['Contracts'=> ['ContractItems' => ['Products' => ['Brands', 'Categories']]]])
    ->where([
            'Contracts.number' => $number,
            'ContractAddresses.postal' => $postal,
            'ContractAddresses.type' => 'S'
            ])
    ->first();
```

Now the `'contractAddresses.postal'` can either be `M1M 1M1` or `M1M1M1` in the database. which means there is a space. now I need to remove that space so it can be compared to `$postal`. I tried doing `str_replace(' ','','ContractAddresses.postal') => $postal` but it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

`'REPLACE (ContractAddresses.postal, " ", "") = ' => $postal`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13675585)

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks! but this is the answer to the question. :)